# compare date strings to json date strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jquery-ui

A User selects a pair of dates from two jquery-ui datepickers, when the user selects the second date both values are compared to strings stored in an external JSON file. If the dates are within the dates below external data is returned to the html page. The dates look like this:

```
"startDate":"01/01/2017",
"endDate":"05/09/2018"
```

I have been unsuccessful in creating an if statement that will successfully compare the date strings from the datepicker can someone point out where I am going wrong when making the if statement?

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
$("#frompicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        $("#topicker").datepicker(null, "minDate", selected);
        date = selected;
        console.log(date);
    }
});
$("#topicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: comparetime
});
var comparetime = function(selected) {
    $("#frompicker").datepicker(null, "maxDate", selected);
    dateObject = selected;
    $('.removeMe').remove();
    $.getJSON('Holidays.json', function(data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.Resorts.length; i++) {
            var d = date;
            var x = dateObject;
            if ((d >= data.Resorts[i].startDate && x < data.Resorts[i].endDate)) {
                console.log(date + " " + dateObject);
                var output = "<section><section class='removeMe container'>";
                output += "<h2>" + data.Resorts[i].name + ", " + data.Resorts[i].destination + "<a href='" + data.Resorts[i].url + "'>Take an In-Depth look</a> " + "</h2>" + "<img src='" + data.Resorts[i].picture + ".jpg'>" + "<article>" + "<p>" + data.Resorts[i].short_description + "</p>" + "<p>Rating: " + data.Resorts[i].Rating + "</p>" + "<p>" + "Price: " + data.Resorts[i].price + "</p>" + "<p>Start Date:" + "<time datetime='" + data.Resorts[i].startDate + "'>" + data.Resorts[i].startDate + "</time></p>" + "<p>End Date: " + "<time datetime='" + data.Resorts[i].endDate + "'>" + data.Resorts[i].endDate + "</time></p>" + "<p> Activities: " + data.Resorts[i].activities + "</p>" + "</article></section></section>";
                $("body").append(output + "<br class='removeMe'>" + "<br class='removeMe'>" + "<br class='removeMe'>" + "<br class='removeMe'>" + "<br class='removeMe'>" + "<br class='removeMe'>" + "<br class='removeMe'>" + "<br class='removeMe'>" + "<br class='removeMe'>");
            }
        }

    });
};
```

**JSON format:**

```
{
      "destination":"Carribean",
      "name":"Les Boucaniers",
      "location":"Martinique",
      "Rating":"4",
      "activities":[
        "WaterSkiing",
        "Tennis",
        "ScubaDiving",
        "Spa"
      ],
      "price":"£1254",
      "startDate":"01/01/2017",
      "endDate":"05/09/2018",
      "short_description":"The resort of Les Boucaniers is located on the laid-back beach-covered south coast of the island, and is perfectly placed for Martinique holidays that are both relaxing and awe-inspiring.",
      "picture":"LesBoucaneers",
      "long_description":"A divers' paradise in the Baie du Marin, a legendary spot.<br>Its bungalows are discreetly lodged in a tropical garden beside the white sand beach in superb Marin Bay. A magical site where you can enjoy a taste of everything, alone or with family or friends. Try water sports and the magnificent Club Med Spa*. You'll be enchanted by the exotic flavours of the local cuisine and the joyful spirit of the Caribbean.",
      "url":"Carribean.html"
}
```

Comment: Hint: Convert date strings to new Date objects and compare

Comment: what is your json format?

Comment: momentjs can help (https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Where is `date` defined? Like when you use: `var d = date;` what is date?

Comment: You cannot compare dates as Sting with `<` or `>`. You will need to convert the string to a Date Object to be able to compare them.